# Error 10022 while listening on UDP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I have written a program to send data and to listen to data via UDP parallel. For this I created several functions:

```
 int initiate_TXRX_variables(void)
{
    struct hostent * hp;
    hp = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if(hp == NULL)
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    memset(&sa_udp_in, 0, sizeof(sa_udp_in));
    memset(&sa_tcp_in, 0, sizeof(sa_tcp_in));
    memset(&sa_udp_out, 0, sizeof(sa_udp_out));
    memset(&sa_tcp_in, 0, sizeof(sa_tcp_in));
    memcpy((char *)&sa_udp_in.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    memcpy((char *)&sa_tcp_in.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    memcpy((char *)&sa_udp_out.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    memcpy((char *)&sa_tcp_out.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    sa_udp_in.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa_tcp_in.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa_udp_out.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa_tcp_out.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa_udp_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)PORTNUM_UDP_IN);
    sa_tcp_in.sin_port = htons((u_short)PORTNUM_TCP_IN);
    sa_udp_out.sin_port = htons((u_short)PORTNUM_UDP_OUT);
    sa_tcp_out.sin_port = htons((u_short)PORTNUM_TCP_OUT);
    return 1;
}

int ultra_spam_network_udp(void)
{
    struct hostent *hp, *local;
    hp = gethostbyname("192.168.70.0");
    hp = gethostbyname("255.255.255.255");
    local = gethostbyname("localhost");
    memcpy((char *)&sa_udp_out.sin_addr,hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    //set_ip_udp_out(htonl(ntohl(sa_udp_out.sin_addr.s_addr) - 1));
    InetPton(AF_INET, "192.168.30.0", &(sa_udp_out.sin_addr));
    char str[] = "Hello";
    char ipstr[256];
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Local: " << retLocalIP() << " and current IP: " << /*inet_ntoa(sa_udp_out.sin_addr)*/InetNtop(AF_INET, &(sa_udp_out.sin_addr), ipstr, 256) << " with counter: " << i << '\n'; 
        sendto(UDP_OUT, str, sizeof(str), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_udp_out, sizeof(sa_udp_out));
        sa_udp_out.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ntohl(sa_udp_out.sin_addr.s_addr)+1);
    };
    //sendto(UDP_OUT, str, sizeof(str), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_udp_out, sizeof(sa_udp_out));
    return 0;
}

int/*char **/ listen_udp_debug(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);
    char inStr[100];
    char * ptr = &inStr[0];
    int ret = recvfrom(UDP_IN, inStr, sizeof(inStr), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
    std::cout << "From listen_udp_debug: " << ret << " with error number " << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
    //return ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

I call these functions via

```
    initiate_TXRX_variables();
    boost::thread thread_1 = boost::thread(ultra_spam_network_udp);
    listen_udp_debug();
```

PORTNUMS for IN and OUT are different, of course. My problem is now that I get the error 10022 when calling `listen_udp_debug()`. Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to circumvent this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `char * ptr = &inStr[0];` is pointless here.  You already have a pointer to the first element in the array via `inStr`

Comment: What is `UDP_IN`?  How is it initialized?

Comment: `SOCKET UDP_IN, UDP_OUT;`, `UDP_IN = socket(hp->h_addrtype, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);`, `struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname("localhost");`. Have I forgotten something?

Comment: Did you check the return value from `socket`?

Comment: Examples I am reading online have people just sending in the address of 'from' without any typecast to (struct sockaddr *). So perhaps, try getting rid of that typecast?

Comment: I get multiple numbers, but never -1 when I check the value of for example UDP_IN or UDP_OUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, I had to use bind() in my udp_receive-function, otherwise it would not work.